# Imagick installation passed with warnings

Tags: config, imagick

I have installed imagick on my amazon lightsail lamp instance like so:

```
apt-get install imagemagick
apt-get install php5-imagick
```

Unfortunately craft tells me that the `ImageMagick extension` has `Passed with warnings`. See this image:

[image]

What am I missing? How do I make sure imagick is working correctly?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use PHP 7 for your Craft install?

Comment: @carlcs I found it more convenient to install php5 and my plan is to use heavy caching with cloudFront later so it shouldn't make a big difference

Comment: I’d still recommend PHP 7 for the speed improvements you’d gain for CP pages.

Comment: @carlcs do you know a good starting point for a craft ready php7 server?

Comment: A very common combo in the Craft community is a 1 GB Digital Ocean VPS provisioned and secured via a (free) ServerPilot account.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "i" graphic and it will probably tell you that GD is installed, but Imagick isn't and it is recommended.

You can verify that Imagick is installed and available to PHP/Craft by going to `yoursite.com/admin/utils/phpinfo` and searching for "imagick".  If it's not there, then it has not been installed properly.

Comment: The "i" says "GD or ImageMagick is required, however ImageMagick is recommended as it adds ...". I can't find "imagick" under phpinfo... on to google...